# How to solder power adapter wires directly on PCB?

Tags: dc, soldering, wire

I’m trying to fix a Dremel that has a broken power adapter jack. I think the best way to repair it would be to solder the power adapter wires directly on the PCB of the Dremel.

There are still 2 wires soldered on the PCB, so I would solder the power adapter wires together with the PCB’s wires (see pictures).

The only part I don’t know is: which wires should I solder together? There is one red and one black on the power adapter, but both are red on the PCB.

Here is the PCB:

[image]

I would remove the black input block and just leave both red wires.

And here is the wire from the power adapter:

[image]

Better view:

[image]

Comment: Connect the black wire to the point on the PCB where the jack connected it.  Do the same for the red wire.  The color of the wires on the original PCB does not matter.

Comment: @user1850479 but the jack is connected to both points on the PCB no? I uploaded a second picture with a better view. Thank you

Comment: Or are you only talking about the wire soldered to the back prong of the black block?

Comment: I would look for a replacement jack socket first, but if you decide to solder the wires to the PCB, don't forget to put in some sort of pull relief, so that pulling the wire doesn't strain the solder joints and the PCB pads.

Comment: Since when are Dremels pink???

Comment: @KyleB It's a Chinese knockoff not the original brand. I used "dremel" as a generic term here.

Comment: The wires should be soldered resting flat against the board, not in the air as in the picture, where all strain is directed just above the joint - that's the point where this wire will break after a while. After soldering it properly, you can use hot glue to give a slight bit of strain relief.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the first picture, I think that is a Barrel Jack. The polarity of it is the outer contact is the -ve polarity and the inner contact is the +ve polarity. It seems in your picture that the wire on the right is the -ve and the one on the left is the +ve.

But you need to check it well beforehand.

When it is confirmed, you can directly solder the Red wire from the adapter to the +ve connection and the Black wire to the -ve.

Comment: If you plan to leave the existing wires in place, you could just cut off the bad jack and splice the wires to your new ones. No need to solder to the PCB. There probably isn't room for wire nuts inside that Dremel case so one option would be to just twist the wires together, add a dab of solder, and wrap with electrical tape.

Comment: It works and is now fully working again! Thanks everybody!